# Lock orientation of a UIViewController on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation, ios8

My app uses a view controller that should be locked into landscape mode. It works perfectly in iOS 6 and 7 but not in iOS 8. I was wondering if anyone heard or read anything about this not working anymore in iOS 8.

My code is calling `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` just fine but ignores the value returned and doesn't transition from portrait to landscape.

My code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```